# If a contraction and its adjoint converge to zero both does that mean the contraction satisfies $ ||Th|| < h $

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I just met this in my functional analysis on contractions which got me stumped:

> Let $ \mathbb{H} $ be a Hilbert space and let T be  a contraction operator on  $ \mathbb{H} $ (meaning $ ||T|| \leq 1 $ in the operator norm) . We are given that 
>   $ \forall h \in \mathbb{H} $ we have the convergence in norm $ T^n \to 0 $ and $ T^{*n} \to 0 $.
>
> And we are asked to determine which (if any) of these three conditions necessarily leads to the property that for all $ h \in \mathbb{H} $ we have $ ||Th || < ||h|| $ ?

I got no idea if this is true or not if only one of the convergences is valid then I know it is not necessarily true, but if both I could not find any counterexamples for this. I thank all who provide the much needed help.

Comment: In the first paragraph, do you mean $T^n h \rightarrow 0$ and $T^{*n}h\rightarrow 0$? Convergence in norm of $T^n \rightarrow 0$ is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $T$ on $\ell^2$ by $$T((x_1,x_2,\dots))=(0,x_1,x_2/2,x_3/3,\dots).$$

Comment: Thanks David, but just to be sure could you please tell me the adjoint operator T*?

Comment: It would be better if you figured out the adjoint for yourself. It's not hard...